# How can I sync Reading List with Windows?

Tags: safari, windows, icloud, reading-list

Is it possible to use Safari's Reading List on my Windows machine and have it synced with the one on my Mac/iOS devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Apple's support docs](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1070), Safari 5.1.1 for Windows will sync the Reading List via iCloud.

> Safari 5.1.1 includes support for iCloud, a breakthrough set of free cloud services. iCloud stores your Safari bookmarks and Safari Reading List and automatically pushes them to all your devices.

I believe you would need to have Safari up to date. Then, install the [iCloud Windows control panel](http://www.icloud.com/icloudcontrolpanel) and configure it to sync Safari content.

[image]

Then, enable iCloud on all of your Mac/iOS devices, and you should be good to go.

Comment: yes, but iCloud isn't supported for Windows XP :(

Comment: Count yourself lucky, iCloud is not supported on Snow Leopard which came out less than 2 years ago... :-)

Comment: Windows XP was released in 2001! (years before Facebook existed and at time when Mac users were using OS 10.1 Puma!!!) Time to move on people...